Databricks Notebooks fails with NoSuchMethodError for a valid method
I'm using Databricks Notebooks / Scala to implement a simple test using Guava BloomFilter class. The library is added to the dependencies and everything looks fine. I can create the BloomFilter and "train"! it using the data I want.
When calling bf.writeTo(...), I get NoSuchMethodError, but the irony is that the method is available:

In the 3 command you see the method being available on the object, but in the 4th command the notebook fails telling me there's no such a method at all.
I've been away from Scala/JVM world for a while, and I'm new to this Notebook setting/env, so I'm not quite sure how I can explain this.
Anyone can help me to explain this and fix it?
